# Is it possible to use JDK11 modules from Groovy? (even if I have to use Groovy 3 alpha)

Tags: javafx, groovy, java-11

Is there a way in Groovy to import code from JDK11 modules such as javafx?  So far, groovyc fails to compile, hitting an error when it imports the JavaFX module's code. I can't even get a HelloWorld groovy script to compile if it imports JavaFX.

A command such as this fails:

```
./groovy3/groovy-3.0.0-beta-2/bin/groovyc grscript.groovy -j -Fmodule-path=/usr/share/openjfx/lib/ -Fadd-modules=javafx.controls:javafx.base


Gives the error:
unable to resolve class javafx.application.Application
@ line 2, column 1.
import javafx.application.Application;
        ^
```

Equivalent HelloJFX.java works just fine. Thus I know everything in OpenJDK11 and OpenJFX is working fine.  It's just the Groovy side of things that is broken.

I am using OpenJDK11 and OpenJFX on Linux, Debian Buster.  I've tried the stable version of Groovy and also the newest alpha of Groovy 3.

I can find almost no information online/anywhere about using Java 11 modules in Groovy.

If the answer is simply "No version of Groovy can use JDK11's modules such as JavaFX"  I'd simply like to know.

Any other ideas very welcome.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the JavaFX jars on the classpath instead of the modulepath and
then add a line like this to your program.

```
class MyProgramLauncher {public static void main(String[] args) {MyProgram.main(args);}}
```

The program must then be launched via this launcher class to make this work.
I don't know what the equivalent for this line is in Groovy but I am sure you can figure that out. I do this all the time in order to avoid all these module system headaches and so far it has never failed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try this and report back.

Comment: I was unfortunately not able to make this work.

After going through the Groovy documentation extensively, and trying many workarounds, the problem remains. This seems to be a problem with current versions of Groovy, which don't understand modules (and can't find them even if they are in the classpath).

An upcoming release is planning to solve this issue.  (The version 3 series, which is pre-release now.) I'll wait for it to be released as final and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

An upcoming release is planning to solve this issue. (The version 3 series, which is pre-release now.) I'll wait for it to be released as final and then try again.

JDK 11 is known not to work in earlier Groovy versions.  In fact Groovy 3 is advertised as being JDK8+ compatible. (Website today says: "Groovy 3.0 is a bleeding edge version of Groovy designed for JDK8+ and with the new Parrot parser enabled by default. Pre-stable versions are available".)